# Randomly Placing Rectangles In SFML

Tags: c++, frameworks, sfml

How would I be able to randomly place the 13 squares, rectangles on a screen that is 800x600?  I tried to use the:

```
    rand() % 800 + 1
    rand() % 600 + 1
```

But it didn't quite work out.  It placed the cubes around the screen on top of each other and off the screen.  Any ideas?  If you need more code, I can edit this to show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your rectangles to overlap each other or to be drawn outside the window, of course it doesn't work very well.

First of, if you do want to see **all** your rectangles, don't randomize their positions between `[0,800]` and `[0,600]` because placing them at 800 width or 600 height will obviously hide them. Instead, for each rectangle, you'd have to randomize with `800-width` and `600-height` as the upper limit.

Secondly, to avoid overlapping rectangles, you'll have to place them one by one and check each time you place a new one that it isn't on top of all the rectangles you placed previously. While it is overlapping, pick another random position. Note that depending on the size of your rectangles and the random positions you get, it might not be possible to do this.